# iOS TabBarItem small space on each side

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs, uitabbar, spacing

So this is the problem I am talking about.

[image]

As you can see, there is a small space in front of Tab1 selection image on the top. I cannot figure out how to delete that space. Currently, items don't have selected image and image assigned, because I don't need one. All I need is text in tabs. So for selection image, I am using TabBar selection property. I added some code, to stretch the selection image, otherwise it is appearing over neighbour tabs.

```
[UITabBar appearance].selectionIndicatorImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"]
                                                  stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
```

Is there any way to remove that space? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The image is wide enough and as I said above, without that code it even covers neighbour tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set imageInset point set in your tabbar item and check i think working good

```
self.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0//topOffset, 0//left, -0//bottomOffset, 0//right);
```

But keep in mind that whatever the value of edgeinset you give, give the opposite value to its opposite side,meaning if you give top 6, then give bottom -6 Or else the image will keep on growing or shrinking after each click.

Hope this will help you great and You're feeling better for your code is working good.

Comment: I have tried with your code but nothing. It doesn't affect the image I put in.

Comment: so you can try image in imageInsets?

Comment: Still nothing. I just don't get it, shouldn't it work and scale everything by itself if I put image in? How can image from tab one overlay image in tab two? And how come it doesn't take full width if I put image large enough in..

Comment: you have selected and noramal image available?

Comment: Yes, couldn't make it work. Found a workaround, which eliminates all the space.
self.tabBar.frame = CGRectInset(self.tabBar.frame,-6,0);

Comment: Sorry, it's a project for a client so can't send my code around. Anyway I solved it, check reply above. Thanks for all the help.